# how to manage ajax response errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, response

I am writing `javascript` app and I am using `backbone.js`.on the app i have ***several views*** in a page, ***majority views*** sent `request` (requests <- they are ajax-query,but  not `backbone.js` ajax-query) to server ***at the same time***, and they had a result in a closely period. If something happened wrong with server or net some `response` would broken and returned with errors. The problem is that all errors **need to display** by alerts to user, despite the fact that it is boring to see more and more alerts for users . How can I manage the alerts?
I used  `settimeout` to show alerts, but this way is not helpful to ***decrease*** count of alerts. 
If You  know another way please tell me about it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    function alertMajorError(errMsg) {
        errMsg = typeof errMsg !== 'undefined' ? errMsg : 'Fatal Error!';
        var n = noty({layout:'center',type:'error',text:errMsg,timeout:false});
    }
    $(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        if (exception == 'abort') return false;
        alertMajorError('An AJAX error [' + exception + '] occurred in script: ' + settings.url + '<br \><br \>Please report this to the development team!');
        console.log(event, jqxhr, settings, exception);
});
```

You can set up a default `AJAX error` reporter in your main JS file like I have. I use the jQuery `noty` plugin!

Comment: P.S. If you're wondering why I ignore the `abort` error, it's because `Autocomplete` and some other async widgets will purposefully abort so they can start over when something changes with the input params. It happens A LOT, so I disabled those.

Answer (score 1):

All the errors must be displayed...
Okay, then just do not alert(), use popup divs with the errors and show them in a notification area, e. g., in the upper left corner of you page.
See how is it made in gmail: when ajax error occurs, a litle notification is shown in the center of the page, a user can read it, but the whole interface is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I read about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and I thought this would help me that time. I hope, this help to others also. Here is [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for handling many request.